# How to recover indexes while generating elements in a svg with d3js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am generating a scatterplot, but I want to do something when I click on the circles (here it call `print_description` which prints some informations about the circle I clicked, I use a more complex function but that's not what the question is about).

```
var circles;
var datas; //defined somewhere else, a big array of objects
var svg = d3.select('#svg');
var scale; //defined somewhere else, a regular d3 scale

function create_circles() {
    svg.selectAll("circle").remove();
    circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
        .data(datas)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .on("click", print_description);
    circles.attr("class", "point")
        .attr("cx", function(d,i) {return scale(d.position[0]);})
        .attr("cy", function(d,i) {return scale(d.position[1]);})
//these functions are not detailed here but don't worry, they work fine:
        .attr("r", function(d,i) {return get_circle_size(d.nature, d.score);})
        .attr("fill", function(d,i) {return get_color_from_nature(d.nature);})
        .attr("opacity", function(d,i) {return get_opacity_from_nature(d.nature);});
}

var focus_circle = "initial";
function print_description(d,i) {
    if (focus_circle != "initial") {
        focus_circle.attr("selected", "false");
    }
    focus_circle = d3.select(circles[0][i]);
    focus_circle.attr("selected", "true");
    d3.select('#nodeInfos').html(d.label+"<br/> "+d.infos);
}
```

Then I want to be able to trigger `print_description` for a given circle without having to click on it, for example I want to trigger it for the circle which corresponds to some value in `datas` when I click on a button.

For example let's say:

```
datas[445] = {
  label: 'Tom',
  position: [5, 17],
  nature: 'friend',
  infos: 'a bit shy, but nice anyway'
}
```

I want to trigger `print_description` as if I clicked on the corresponding circle when I press a button.

```
var lab = 'Tom';
searchBtn.onclick = function() {
    print_description(??); //what can I use as arguments here ?
};
```

Any idea about how to do that ?

Comment: Maybe use `circles.filter(function(d) { return d.label === lab })` to select your item back ?

Comment: Doing this by index seems quite cumbersome and error-prone. Is there any other key you might use? How do you identify your datum when hitting the search button?

Comment: @altocumulus The value of `lab` comes from a user input. The user doesn't know the indexes, only the labels so I have to do my search from that.

Comment: @AnneAunyme And is this a unique key or are there any duplicate labels in your `datas` variable?

Comment: I can't be sure the label is unique, but there shouldn't be any duplicates.

Comment: @TimB It seems I need this "i" argument, and this only provides a circle element, not its index.

Comment: You can do `circles.filter(function(d, i) { // do stuff })`

Comment: won't that do the stuff for all circles ?